# Verilog Event control statements

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I currently have this code(below) for a debouncer for a button on an fpga, however I am getting an error that says "Multiple event control statements in one always/initial process block are not supported in this case." whenever I try to synthesize the desgin. The line that causes the problem is the `@(posedge clk)` but I'm wondering how exactly to replace this logic. What I essentially require is `always @ (quarter & posedge clk)`as the sensitivity list for the first always block but this does not work either. I am fairly new to the language so I'm still working out a few syntax kinks.Snippet of Code is below:

```
always @(quarter)
        begin

            @(posedge clk)
             begin
                 if (quarter != new) begin new <= quarter; count <= 0; end
                 else if (count == DELAY) cleanq <= new;
                 else count <= count+1;
              end
          end
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of always

```
@(posedge event1)         
@(posedge event2)
create aflag (1bit reg) event2done :   reg event2done; initial event2done=0;
always@(posedge event1)
begin       if (!event2done & event 2)
        // event2done=1; + type ur code 
            else if(event2done & !event 2)
                event2done =0;  end
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer by using backquote to comment the code parts (ex : `this is code`) it's really unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

pseudo code:

```
always@(something1)
           @(something2)
                 do something
```

Look in the comments to see explanation as to why this isn't synthesizable

```
always @(posedge clk)
             /* over here you'll have to set the default values
                for everything that's being changed in this always block, 
                you'll otherwise generate latches. Which is likely
                not what you want */
             begin
                 if (quarter != new) begin new <= quarter; count <= 0; end
                 else if (count == DELAY) cleanq <= new;
                 else count <= count+1;
              end
```

I don't have access to my verilog rig at the moment so I can't confirm the syntax correctness

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you put in your comment block. Do you mean you basically initialize your "variables"? If yes, I'm struggling to see how this represents the same logic. The block of code should execute on posedge and upon "quarter" press.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `always @(something1)  @(something2) do something` is interpreted as wait for the something1 event, then wait for the something2 event next. There is no way to write or synthesized code for for two events to happen at the same exact time. Most synthesis tools only allow one event in an always block.

Comment: @dave_59 I might have been wrong about that. Antoninus what do you mean by "quarter press" , it's value has changed? I don't mean initialize the values, I mean be explicit about their values. So if a value is unchanged you'd put value <= value;

Comment: yeah its value basically changes from 0 to 1 when you press the button. I see what you mean now but it does not really allow me to represent the same logic. I did find a way around it though but thanks for all your help!